# How to pass current user between components in Angular2?

Tags: angular2-services, angular2-components

I have spent the past ~5 hours attempting to learn how to implement observables, subjects, behavior subjects, etc and can't seem to fully grasp how to do this.  Essentially, I have a login component.  Login component calls auth.service.ts which makes an http call to authenticate the user.

After successfully logging in the user, I go to another.component.ts.  I want another.component.ts to have access to the this.currentUser in auth.service.ts file.

Code:

```
** login.component.ts **

// this works -> authenticates user and sends to home page
this.authService.authenticateUser(this.loginUser)
  .subscribe((response) => {
    this.router.navigate([/'homePage']);
  });



** auth.service.ts **

  public signedInUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

  // gets called when user submits login form
  authenticateUser(user) {
    let route = "http://localhost:3000/login";

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(route, user, { headers: headers })
      .map((response) => {
        ??? set this.signedInUser ???
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((error)  => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
      })
  }


  // I tried implementing this functionality
  // I think one of the issues is I can't figure out where
  // to put this.signedInUser.next();

  subscribeToCurrentUser() {
    return this.signedInUser.asObservable();
  }




** another.component.ts **
// I want access to this.authService.signedInUser
   it currently is undefined
   I even added {{ currentUser.firstName | async }}
   and it didn't work
```

I can't quite seem to figure out how to piece all of this together.  Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==== FOUND THE ANSWER ====

```
*** login.component.ts ***
this.authService.authenticateUser(this.loginUser);

** auth.service.ts **

  public signedInUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

  // gets called when user submits login form
  authenticateUser(user) {
    let route = "http://localhost:3000/login";

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post(route, user, { headers: headers })
      .map((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((error)  => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
      })
      .subscribe((response) => {
        this.currentUser.setCurrentUser(response.user);
      })
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    return this.signedInUser.asObservable();
  }

  setCurrentUser(user) {
    this.currentUser.next(user);
  }




** another.component.ts **
this.authService.getCurrentUser()
    .subscribe((user) => {
       this.currentUser = user;
    })
```